# How do I configure PuTTy so the tilde (~) is selected with the rest of the filepath?

Tags: putty, console

When I double-click a filepath in my PuTTy console the entire path is selected, provided the path contains no spaces or certain characters like "%" or ";". Unfortunately, PuTTy also considers "~" to be one of those certain characters. Since I use paths starting with ~/... and ~user/... a lot, I like the behavior I get with mintty in cygwin much better as it selects the ~ with the rest of the path (which improves my efficiency). Is there a way to get the same behavior in PuTTy?

Answer (score 8):

Came across this since I wanted to do the same thing. Hopefully this isn't too late, but this is how I was able to do it.

Open Putty -> Change Settings -> Selection (under "Window") ->
- Scroll down in the Character Classes box and select ~
- In "Set to class", put 2 and hit "Set"

Now you can go back to Session -> Select saved session -> Save -> Apply

Comment: Why 2? Because the other characters you want to select with it [a-zA-Z0-9] and others are already class 2. https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-charclasses

Comment: you saved my life.